# Find all commas between two seperate characters in string

Tags: regex

I have a substring that contains commas. This substring lives inside of another string that is a semi colon delimited list. I need to match the commas in that substring.  The substring has a key field "u3=" in front of it.

Example:

```
u1=something;u2=somethingelse;u3=cat,matt,bat,hat;u4=anotherthing;u5=yetanotherthing
```

Regex so far:

```
(?<=u3)(.*)(?=;)
```

The regex i've been working on above matches everything between "u3" and the last ";" in the outerstring.  I need to match only the commas in the substring.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Get the indices of the commas? Split the data apart? Something that looks like this, I'd expect you just wanted to split the string first by semi-colons to get key-value pairs, then by equals sign to get the key and value, then split the value by comma to get the unique values.

Comment: What is language?

Comment: I don't think regex is sufficient for this alone. It's not clear what you mean by `match` – do you want the position of the commas, or just their presence, or a count of them? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Remember regex matches a string... you commas interject at various points within a string. So what exactly are you trying to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You didn't specify language!*

C#, VB (.NET):

Using an infinite positive lookbehind,

```
(?<=u3=[^;]*),
```

Java:

Using a variable-length positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=u3=[^;]{0,9999}),
```

PHP (PCRE), Perl, Ruby:

Using `\G` along with `\K` token:

```
(?>u3=|\G(?!^))[^,;]+\K,
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/WheXRJ/2)

JavaScript:

Using two `replace()` methods (if you are going to substitute),

```js
var s = 'u1=something;u2=somethingelse;u3=cat,matt,bat,hat;u4=anotherthing;u5=yetanotherthing';

console.log(
  s.replace(/u3=[^;]+/, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/,/g, '*');
  })
)
```

Comment: Glad, please tag your question with a language.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regex:

```
(?<=u3)[^;]+
```

The result is:

```
=cat,matt,bat,hat
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was PHP I would do this:

```
<?php

$str = 'u1=something;u2=somethingelse;u3=cat,matt,bat,hat;u4=anotherthing;u5=yetanotherthing;';
$split = explode(';', $str);

foreach ($split  as $key => $value) {
    $subsplit = explode('=',$value);
    if ($subsplit[0] == 'u3') {
        echo $subsplit[1];
        preg_match_all('/,/', $subsplit[1], $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    }    
}

var_dump($matches);
```